# How to reduce the lag time when using jquery to modify css onload

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function that is called on $(document).ready that modifies the css of a Business Intelligence dashboard. I had to use jquery to make the adjustments because I do not have access to the source code of the BI tool. What happens is when the page loads, I run through the tab navigation and change the colors of the tabs based on certain requirements (which is basically dependent on the text of the tab). The issue I am facing is that there is a small lag time from when the page initially loads to when the jquery updates have been made to the page. Is there a way to reduce this lag time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Eric's answer, I would hide the part of your page that shows the BI tool, or the whole body if you like (perhaps replaced with a 'Loading...' type message)  Then, as the last line of  your $(document).ready() code make the container visible again and remove the 'Loading...' message.

Here's a what I'm thinking:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='BIContainer' style='display:none;'>
 <!-- BI TOOL OUTPUT GOES HERE -->
</div>

<!-- I'm assuming jQuery has already been loaded -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Your code to change the tab styles
        $('#BIContainer').show();
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for you guys responses. These solutions make sense... the problem is that I do not have access to the html like shown above... The only place I can make modifications is onload using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Nevermind... Thanks a ton guys. I just went ahead and set display:none in the css for that specific div, then I show it after the modifications have been made. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the transition neater by hiding the containing `div`, applying your CSS changes, and then artistically fading the modified dashboard `div` in.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you use `.css()` to modify your style?
Make custom classes in a seperate CSS file you crate, then just `addClass()` its much faster. If you cant to that, i would suggest you use Eric's solution.

Comment: Yup, I am already using addClass and removeClass. The lag was still present even with this route. The solution was to hide the div completely (the one with the tabs in it), make the css modifications through jquery code, then show the div with the tabs. Works like a charm and the client is now happy. Thanks everyone!